# Using $q_A(x)=x^tAx$, the quadratic form associated with $A$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In my notes on finding the local extrema ,I had the following extract :

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix ,a principal submatrix of size $k$ is the submatrix with first $k$ columns and first $k$ rows .Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and let $\det A\neq 0$ .Denote by $A_k$ its principal $k^{th}$ submatrix .Write $q_A(x)=x^tAx$, the quadratic form associated with $A$.
>   Then
>   $1.)$ $q_A$ is positive definite if and only if $det(A_k)\gt 0$ .
>   $2.)$ $q_A$ is negative definite if and only if $(-1)^kdet(A_k)\gt 0$ .
>   $3.)$ $q_A$ is positive indefinite if neither $1.$ or $2.$ hold .

I can't understand for what purpose was it stated ...and what application does it have in finding local extrema

Kindly help me with this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second order multivariable taylor's theorem for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is

$$
f(x+h) = f(x)+ \nabla f(x) \cdot h + \frac{1}{2}h^\top H(f)(x) h + \mathcal{o}(h^2) 
$$

where $H(f)(x)$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$ at the point $x$.

At a critical point, the first order term vanishes, and $f$ is well approximated locally by the quadratic form whose matrix is given by $H(f)(x)$.

If this matrix is positive definite, then input $h$ into the quadratic form results in a positive number, so $f$ is increasing in all directions $h$.  This implies that $f$ has a local minimum at $x$.  Similarly if the hessian is negative definite, $f$ has a local maximum.

The theorem you wrote down lets you decide if a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is positive or negative definite by just computing $n$ different determinants.

Another method which would tell you more information would be to find an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of orthogonal eigenvectors of the hessian.  This is possible by the real spectral theorem.  If all eigenvalues are positive, then pos definite.  If all negative, then negative definite.  If the eigenvalues have mixed signs, then you have saddles, with some directions increasing and some decreasing away from the point.  A zero eigenvalue gives you no information:  you have to compute higher order effects to get information in those directions.

A note:  to really understand the higher order taylor's theorem, you have to learn a little tensor calculus.  The $k^{th}$ derivative is a $k^{th}$ order symmetric tensor, just as the hessian is a second order symmetric tensor.

Comment: but we already know that if the eigenvalues are all negative then ,we get local maximum ...and if positive then we get local minima ,then what is use of the above quadratic form.. kindly help..

Comment: The quadratic form is the approximation! To understand the second derivative test in single variable calculus, would you agree it is helpful to think about a parabola?

The use of the theorem you gave above about the quadratic form is that instead of finding all the eigenvalues (hard) you can just compute $n$ determinants (easy).

Comment: thanks for the explanation...